# ezdz jQuery plugin doesn't call accept when upload the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](https://github.com/jaysalvat/ezdz) jQuery plugin to upload/validate images. Although when I select the same image for the (for the iput taq) the `ezdz.accept` function is not called(nor reject is called). I is only called if the image is different.

How to make it to evoke the function every time immage is loaded, no matter it is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer: Just clear the input value at the end of the `accept` function, so next time it doesn't know it is the same imamge.

```js
accept: function(file) {
      $(".ezdz-dropzone.ezdz-accept span").remove();
      ......
      ......
      $('.new-upload-2')[0].value = null; // This is where the value us cleared
    }
  });
```